# Beating “A Good Deal at Any Price”

Tags: economy

Over the summer, I had the privilege of listening to a Cherokee storyteller. One of the many things he mentioned was his take on trade between the new colonists and his people.

The gun, he said, was a good bargain for the Cherokee. He provided examples: how, if a bear was outside your house in the middle of the night, and arrow wasn’t going to bother that thing - you had to risk your own life to go outside with a club and try to drive the bear off... or, you could fire a single shot in the air with a gun. When hunting, the amount of effort that went into making a single few arrows : building a fire around a tree to sweat the tree for sap, curing the sap down to glue, harvesting beeswax and mixing it into glue to keep the glue solid in the heat, adding the glue after securing arrowheads to arrows with twine - saved hours and hours of work off each meal.

As the storyteller described it, even as the quality of guns being sold went down (hand-me-downs, rejects) and the price went up (to enough deer hide to be worth hundreds of thousands of dollars in modern prices) a gun was still a good long term investment, so many worked tirelessly bringing in (and overhunting) enough leather to pay for it.

I have been thinking about this for world building purposes for months, and can’t imagine any way out of this trap. How does a mostly self-governed nation escape being destroyed by a technology that is so useful, that even if the people have to spend themselves into poverty to get it, they will feel like they sincerely made the right choice?

Comment: (as someone who makes bows and arrows in my spare time i have to say: making simple arrows for hunting is a much, much simpler and quicker process than described. also i'd argue that you stand much better chances against a bear with bow&arrow than with a club)

Comment: i don't see the problem. if they think it's worth the effort, then it's worth it for them.

Comment: Like @ths said, there is no problem to be solved. If the piece of technology is useful for them then, or, in economics jargon, it has great utility, then it is useful for them. How did mostly self-governed and relatively small nations such as Japan or South Korea escape from being destroyed by technolgy? And anyway the problem is badly framed. It was not technology in itself which defeated the American Indians in the USA. It was a well-defined enemy; compare with many South American countries where mixed-race people are the majority. Native languages are official in Bolivia, Paraguay, Peru...

Comment: Well, to a Cherokee --or anybody else-- who doesn't want to be exploited and colonized and marginalized under some (foreign) overseer, it sure DOES seem like a problem to be solved.

Comment: And this quote is contrary to the experience of the Commanche who found that guns were not that effective in battle as the bow and arrow. They could shoot the guy with a gun five times while he was trying to reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several historical answers to the economics question. The politics will determine which policies gets pursued.

**Import restrictions** and other forms of regulation.

- You can depress demand (and incidental murders) to a degree by specifying that guns must be a certain size, or weight, or quality, or must be "approved", or the user properly trained and licensed, or the transaction recorded. Of course, this assumes that the self-governing society has the capability to monitor and enforce such regulation. And the capability to deter off-sheet transactions.
- You can also regulate powder and ammunition...to an extent.
- You can have less-restrictive regulations for domestic production.

Development of **domestic production**.

- Send your clever young folks to school to learn how to locate iron ore and coal and lead and other elements in the ground, how to mine them, how to make steel and powder from them, and how to craft the final products.
- And how to build and manage factories and workers. And how to build banks and companies to manage the moneys required. You will need literate urban class to keep track of all those records. You will need teamsters to carry the goods from factory to factory. And lawyers and saloonkeepers to mediate conflicts.

**Invention of alternatives**.

- Sometimes you don't need to **duplicate** an expensive good. The economic principle of *substitution* says that folks will choose a cheaper, equally-desirable substitute.
- Example: Let's say your self-governing society doesn't need firearms for wars or the murderous rampages of internal politics -- just hunting. And those smart young kids in school learn about blowguns. They don't require the development of steel or powder or lead industries. Just some bamboo seeds and plant husbandry. A domestic blowgun could be much cheaper (and lighter) than a domestic firearm...making it an acceptable *substitute* for many hunters.
- Of course, the REAL reason folks in our societies prefer firearms today has nothing to do with hunting animals. Bow-hunting is still very popular. Humans prefer the range, surprise, rate-of-fire, and threat value of firearms *primarily for use against other humans*. Depending upon how your worldbuilding and societies result, some of those characteristics might be valuable, some might not. Some might be eligible for substitution, some might not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, there were plenty of natives that learned English, brought tutors into their villages, or sent their children to schools abroad - yet, that didn’t produce (to my knowledge) any native-made gun (in this example). Do you know why?

Comment: Indeed, one branch of my family tree descends from a nation in North America that did exactly that. However, their rich agricultural lands held little accessible coal, iron ore, and other  key resources. And they didn't get the hang of banks, companies, and other institutions required to pool the effort and marshal resources. And, of course, the local Colonial power usually used their influence in various ways to keep the nations dependent upon their support and to actively prevent the development of independent institutions and industry.

Answer (score 3):

**Learn that Technology**

Some very poor nations have learnt to enrich uranium and make nuclear bomb.

Some countries with not much resources have developed missile program.

**Create some kind of threat**

If you have some kind of resources needed by others, bargain them for what you need.

Comment: This was my first thought also. I haven’t had a chance to research why this didn’t happen

Comment: @JamesMcLellan you need something of an industrial base to make guns and gunpowder. They're somewhat less convenient than horses in that regard. Not every society has the wherewithal to make firearms, but trading for completed items or key components is potentially open to everyone.

Comment: Also, note that making nukes is not exceptionally difficult if you have the materials, but uranium enrichment is awkward. Building missiles and rockets is one thing, but making the likes of an ICBM is extremely hard... much more so than making warheads. Consider that the "very poor nations" have been gifted, or have somehow traded, critical components that they're unable to produce themselves.

Comment: No country gifts or trades uranium ore or a centrifuge for uranium enrichment. These two things must be produced by the country itself. Critical components can be smuggled.

Answer (score 3):

> How does a mostly self-governed nation escape being destroyed by a technology that is so useful

Concentrating on the technology is kinda missing the point... the gun was surely very important, but it was just one artifact brought by colonial powers. A society-wide refusal to trade for guns doesn't wedge the genie back in the bottle. The [Outside Context Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excession#Outside_Context_Problem) has already arrived, and it will almost inevitably bring with it sweeping societal changes or complete destruction.

Even if you *do* refuse, the continued existence of your society in its current form is effectively at the mercy of the people with the technology. Even if you refuse it, could you plausibly fight them off? Maybe, but in the course of that war your society *will* change. If you refuse a technology but your neighbours accept it, they now have an economic or military advantage over you. And so on.

No, you either have to accept that things *will* change, and try as best you can to adapt your own society (possibly the [Meiji restoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiji_Restoration) is an example of this) or you rely on the indulgence of a strong neighbour (Bhutan's relationship with India might be an example of this). Burying your head in the sand invites annihilation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the final question, how to **prevent** adoption of an incredibly useful technology, I think the answer is cultural pride bordering on religion. Self-pride. Like Spartan pride, at being warriors.

For example:

> We follow the paths of our ancestors, and they did not have guns. We
> don't take the easy way out, it is dishonorable, it is corrupting, it
> is laziness, we have survived ten thousand years without change,
> through hard times and good times, and we are still here. Because we
> are tough. We work hard. And if we stop doing that, we become lost,
> and confused, we become the other and our way of life will cease to
> be.
>
> We do not need guns, we survive by our wits, in partnership with
> nature, as our ancestors did. That is the only way we survive, without
> it, the Cherokee cease to be.

Something like that.

Comment: The spartans who would have taken pride in being warriors were the aristocratic elite. The society as a whole was reasonably effectively controlled by those elite who wanted to maintain their own wealth and power. So "spartan pride" probably won't prevent technological adoption, but brutal oppression by a warrior elite might do a fairly good job.

Comment: @StarfishPrime As I said, similar. Not exactly the same. Pride **like** that of the Spartans, felt throughout society, can do the trick. **Like** a religion, for example in Christianity and Islam and Judaism, the devout, men and women, will both often subscribe to the irrational notion that only men are qualified to be leaders of other men. If you want a society to do something irrational, like refuse to use guns, then give them an irrational belief system, to which they are devoutly committed, that demands such a decision.

Comment: If I could give two answer check marks, I would. This, also, sounds like an excellent way out of the trap. Thank you!

Comment: @JamesMcLellan You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Steal the technology.

Repeatedly during the industrial revolution and today with the information revolution, countries that found themselves wanting the technology have stolen it. For example, Britain had a monopoly on weaving looms for a while. They had laws preventing anyone who knew the technology from leaving the country. The information was smuggled out in someone's head and brought to America where we proceeded to build many mills. Likewise, today it is common knowledge that sending a design to another country will wind up with that design being built by a competitor in that country.

It is almost impossible to keep the knowledge of how to build a technology secret. Someone will see the making of it, take that knowledge someplace else, and use it. Seeds will be smuggled. Rare minerals will be found in the black market. Tooling will be stolen. Plan on people stealing any special sauce or recipe you have.

Comment: Theft of technology requires an appropriate industrial base to build upon. If your society does not already have a tradition of mining, smelting, metalworking and basic chemical work, DIY firearms are going to be challenging. The changes required to produce a new technology locally may be no less destructive to society than purchasing the finished product.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to craft the indispensable item.

Real-world example:

> Tanegashima (matchlock)
> The lord of the Japanese island Tanegashima Tokitaka (1528–1579) purchased two matchlock muskets from the Portuguese and put a swordsmith to work in copying the matchlock barrel and firing mechanism. ... From 1560, firearms were used in large battles in Japan.

He bought two weapons, one for testing as a control group, and the other to be disassembled and copied. When they came to conquer japan, they had firearms, leveling the playing field and safeguarding their independence.

Comment: Natives learned English, brought tutors into their homes, or sent their children abroad to study, but this didn’t lead to native-made guns (as far as I know). Do you know why?

Comment: Well, this example is specific that it DID lead to native-made guns.

Comment: @jamesmclellan this is one success case in human history.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Competitive Marketplace.**

Your story has only a single seller. That seller has a monopoly on guns and can dictate whatever price they like. The solution is to find a second seller to compete with the first one.

For example if the Americans are trying to sell you guns for the price of ten thousand deer hides, you should go to the Canadians for your guns instead. The Canadians are not on speaking terms with the Americans. This is good for you as it prevents them cooperating to keep the prices high.

Instead both sides will lower their prices to outbid the other until the price of the gun ends up at 30 deer hides. This is about $20 to an American which is about the same price as a rifle.

If all goes well our culture will be safe from intrusion by foreign technology for the rest of time. The Americans and Canadians will both stop selling us guns in exchange for deerhides. Instead they sell us bullets in exchange for our lives. i.e they shoot us with their guns and take our deerhides. Mission complete!

Comment: This actually happened...but it didn't go well. The British in 1811 readily agreed to sell weapons --cheap-- to a growing federation of Ohio Valley nations threatened by expanding settlement in Ohio and Indiana. A spy leaked the news to the Americans, who marched a small, rag-tag force and defeated the nations at the Battle of Tippecanoe before the first shipments arrived.